# How to find 2 specific .py files and run them

Tags: python

I have 2 '.py' files in many sub-folders. And would like to run them one at a time.
First, I would like to run the first one in all sub-folders and then run the second. Also, lets say the first one is named AAA and the second is BBB.

Below is my script.

```
import os
import sys

rootdir = os.getcwd()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        #print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if filepath.endswith("A*.py or B*"):
            print(filepath)


os.startfile(filepath)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (filepath.endswith("A*.py" or "B*")):
    os.startfile(filepath)
    print(filepath)
```

Comment: sorry but `filepath.endswith("A*.py" or "B*")` can't work. it evaluates to `filepath.endswith('A*.py')` and wildcards aren't supported in endswith too.

Comment: Hi guys, i tried this, it still didn't work. What i actually want to do is run 2 python scripts automatically. First "AAA" and then "BBB"

Answer (score -1):

The `if filepath.endswith("A*.py or B*"):` is the problem. The str.endswith doesn't work like this. This condition should work:

```
if file == "AAA.py" or file = "BBB.py":
```

Also start the file in the if block, so this is the full code:

```
import os
import sys

rootdir = os.getcwd()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        #print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if file == "AAA.py" or file = "BBB.py":
            print(filepath)
            os.startfile(filepath)
```